# Error trying to process zipped entry: Error while trying to unzip the file using kettle

Tags: etl, unzip, kettle, zip

I have a zip file in unix where i try to unzip it using Pentaho Kettle. The zip file has 777 access and it works well for unzipping files. But when i try to use it for one particalar zipped folder it was throwing following error:

2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Error trying to process zipped entry [zip:file:///data/dev/inbound/Clarabridge/Sears_Reactive_Export_20160620.zip!/psv_pd_social_username.csv] from file [file:///data/dev/inbound/Clarabridge/Sears_Reactive_Export_20160620.zip] !
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:46)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:464)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:247)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.unzip.JobEntryUnZip.unzipFile(JobEntryUnZip.java:749)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.unzip.JobEntryUnZip.processOneFile(JobEntryUnZip.java:523)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.unzip.JobEntryUnZip.execute(JobEntryUnZip.java:467)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:714)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:856)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:856)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:856)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:530)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:422)
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Unzip file - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Success condition was broken! Total errors : 1
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Abort job - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Aborting job.
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Kitchen - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Finished with errors
error Occurred
 - jb_mso_clarabridge_101_unzip_files_set_daterange - Finished job entry [Unzip file] (result=[false])
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - jb_mso_clarabridge_101_unzip_files_set_daterange - Finished job entry [Delete folders] (result=[false])
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - jb_mso_clarabridge_101_unzip_files_set_daterange - Finished job entry [Transformation] (result=[false])
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - jb_mso_clarabridge_101_unzip_files_set_daterange - Job execution finished
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Kitchen - Finished!
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Kitchen - Start=2016/06/21 05:22:44.842, Stop=2016/06/21 05:22:47.183
2016/06/21 05:22:47 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 2 seconds.

Please suggest on various possible scenarios where this error occurs. And any solution for this error is highly appreciated

Comment: What is zip file size?

Comment: What filenames encoding in zip file? Java zip entry support UTF8 only. Good if u have only ascii characters of entries. Bad if not, and encoding not an UTF8

Comment: Zip file size is 3.12 GB

Comment: And zip file name is Export_20160619.zip

Answer (score 0):

It looks like unzipped file is bigger then 4Gb.

**The support for ZIP64, the format for > 4G ZIP file, has finally been added into the latest OpenJDK7 build(b55).**

Ensure that u have JDK7_(>55) or JDK8 used in pentaho.

There is issues in kettle with jdk8, at least on version u use.